# How do I differentiate between MotionEvent.ACTION_UP and dragging a finger off-screen in Android?

Tags: android, gesture, touchscreen, motionevent

My application is a grid of buttons, edge to edge.  I'm overriding all touch and motion events and controlling the behavior manually.  Everything is working fine, except for when a finger is dragged off-screen.  MotionEvent.ACTION_UP is triggered, and I don't want that.  I tried using getRawX() and getRawY() to determine if (for example, for the top and left edges) the coordinate is < 1, but the value will be higher (as high as 20) if a finger is dragged quickly.  When ACTION_UP is triggered, the location values seem to lag behind a bit.  Is there a way around this?  ACTION_CANCEL doesn't seem to get triggered at all.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN):
        Log.i(classID, "action down");
        return true;
    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL):
        Log.i(classID, "action cancel");
        // never called
        return true;
    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE):
        Log.i(classID, "action move");
        return true;
    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP):
        Log.i(classID, "action up");
        Log.i(classID, "position: " + (int)event.getRawX() + "/" + (int)event.getRawY());
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "off-screen", like literally dragging your finger until it falls off the phone? Or just outside of your particular widget's rectangle? I'm not sure why Android would should report a different event based on the direction your finger is moving when it leaves the phone. I'm curious why you need this?

Comment: I mean dragging a finger until it's out of the bounds of the screen.  It would actually take a pretty lengthy description to tell you what my app does, but it involves the user pressing/sliding on the screen while looking at visual feedback on a computer.  So it's possible the user could drag their finger off, and I don't want anything to trigger if that happens.

Answer (score 2):

There is physical or logical no difference between the two (finger falling off the screen and lifting your finger). When your finger goes off the screen, you have "lifted ", or, better worded, removed your finger from the screen. MotionEvent.ACTION_UP is a place holder for any motion event that results in no touch input data being provided to the system.

If you wish to work around this, you could possibly create a parent view and child view. If the touch is "lifted" from the child view but still in the parent, the finger is still on the device but out of bounds.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I suppose then, since the entire display is a subclass of RelativeLayout, I can just put a 5 px (or so) border around the grid of buttons and detect when a finger is no longer on a button.  The user is supposed to drag their finger off-screen to cancel an action, so perhaps this border can be the "cancel region".

Comment: @ultra Essentially. That's how I would do it.

Answer (score 0):

What he said about there being 'no physical difference' between the finger being *lifted off* the screen and the finger being *swiped out* of the borders of your **View** is incorrect.

You can prove so by merely having a **SurfaceView** in the middle of your screen, and in the **OnTouch** event callback, have an **IF** statement such as:

```
if (event.getEvent() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
         Log.d("derp", "finger has lifted up");
}
```

You'll see that it doesn't actually report if your finger merely goes out of the boundaries. Although there is a **MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE**, I can't seem to get it working. Hence why I'm looking about here too.